# String to LocalDate conversion issue

Tags: java, date-conversion, localdate

I have a SpringBoot 2.6.14 web-app with JPA 2.2 and Hibernate 5.

Now I have a String with this format

```
"2024-03-04T14:10:37.000Z"
```

And, following some instruction (googling around) I write the following String to LocalData converter:

```
default LocalDate stringToDate(String data) {
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) return null;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    return LocalDate.parse(data, formatter);
}
```

The parsing works but the result is 2024-03-04, the hour, minutes and seconds are truncated.
What's wrong?

Comment: You probably want `return LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.parse(data), ZoneId.systemDefault());` *The parsing works but the result is 2024-03-04, the hour, minutes and seconds are truncated. What's wrong?* You got what you asked for - a (Local) *date*. Maybe you want `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: "the hour, minutes and seconds are truncated" - sure, `LocalDate` is a date only, if you want time: `LocalDateTime`, but since your string also contains a time zone: `ZonedDateTime` (which then can be converted to a `LocalDateTime` -- `ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-03-04T14:10:37.000Z").toLocalDateTime()` (or `...toLocalDate()`) (no formatter needed since already in ISO-8601 format)

Answer (score 2):

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), as the name suggests, does not include a time. Consider using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead.

```java
return LocalDateTime.parse(data, formatter);
```

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

- *Never* put quote marks around the `Z`. That discards vital information.
- For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```java
Instant
.parse( "2024-03-04T14:10:37.000Z" )
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )
.toLocalDate()
```

Or:

```
LocalDate
.ofInstant (
    Instant.parse( "2024-03-04T14:10:37.000Z" ) ,
    ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" )
)
```

### No, not `LocalDateTime`

Both Answers recommending the `LocalDateTime` classes are wrong.

That class represents a date with a time-of-day. But your string input contains a third component: offset from the temporal meridian, UTC.

Your input represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. But the `LocalDateTime` object cannot represent a moment.

A `LocalDateTime` object is inherently ambiguous. If we had a LocalDateTime object for noon on January 23rd of 2024, we have no way of knowing if that means noon in Tokyo Japan , noon in Toulouse France , or noon in Toledo Ohio US  — three different moments several hours apart.

### `Instant`

The `Z` on the end indicates on offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. This abbreviation of `+00:00` is defined in the ISO 8601 standard.

Parse your input as a `Instant` object to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2024-03-04T14:10:37.000Z" ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

To get a date from a moment, you **must specify a time zone**. For any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. A single moment can simultaneously be “tomorrow” in Tokyo while also “yesterday” in Toledo.

Define the time zone through which you want to view the date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

Apply that zone to our instant to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Both the `Instant` object and the `ZonedDateTime` object represent the very same moment, the same point on the timeline.

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Comment: Yes, it's certainly the case that a destination type of `LocalDateTime` is discarding information from the original datum. But we really need CoderJammer to tell us what the *ultimate* persistence data type is. As usual, it would have been better to [state the goal and not the step](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)